# ¿A qué se refiere con inicializar un objeto de una clase?

Tags: javascript, typescript, constructor

Tengo una duda muy grande en la parte de constructores sobre la frase "inicializar un objeto de una clase". El concepto de constructor refiere a que un constructor esa es su función, inicializar un objeto de una clase, la cual me temo no entiendo muy bien.

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que no entiendes? ¿Qué has investigado?

Comment: He investigado sobre conceptos generales y esas cosas, pero a como comentaba en la pregunta, ese término de "Inicialización" de objetos es el que no entiendo con claridad.

Comment: Un objeto como ya dijiste se inicializa en el constructor, que asigna a la instancia que se crea las propiedades intrínsecas del mismo. Por ejemplo, `Persona` tiene propiedades como `nombre, apellido...` cuando creas una instancia de `Persona` le pasas al constructor el `nombre` y el `apellido` y esa instancia del objeto es inicializada con esa información.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Un constructor es una subrutina que te permite crear un objecto en base a la jerarquía definida por los parámetros declarados en una clase.

Ejemplo:

```
class Rectangulo {

    int x;
    int y;
    int ancho;
    int alto;

    Rectangulo(int x1, int y1, int w, int h) { // Nuestro constructor
        x = x1;
        y = y1;
        ancho = w;
        alto = h; 
    }

}
```

Para crear un objeto de una clase se usa la palabra reservada `new`.

```
Rectangulo nuevoRectangulo = new Rectangulo(10, 20, 40, 80);
```

Por lo que hemos creado `nuevoRectangulo` que es una variable de tipo `Rectangulo` inicializada con los valores:

- `x` = 10
- `y` = 20
- `ancho` = 40
- `alto` = 80

Para poder acceder a esos datos es tan simple como generar los respectivos setters & getters ([más información aquí](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_encapsulation.asp)) en nuestra clase.

Answer (score 2):

Cuando creas una clase

```
class Conexion 
{
}
```

Estas indicando la plantilla o estructura base que en si misma va a contener:

- Métodos
- Propiedades

Que hacen referencia a la clase en si misma

Al momento de declarar un constructor así

```
class Conexion 
{ 
    constructor(param1, param2)
    {
         this.param1 = param1
         this.param2 = param2
    }
}
```

Le estás indicando a la clase que al momento de ser instanciada por un objeto, va a requerir 2 parámetros, pues el constructor es el primer método que se ejecuta una vez que la clase es inicializado y tiene pasados como argumentos dos.

Ahora puedes pasarle un segundo método que:

- Tome dichos parámetros que la clase requería para ser creada
- Realizar alguna operación con los datos

Codigo

```
showData() {
   return this.param1......
}
```

Finalmente al momento de hacer la instancia le indicas

El objeto `let instancia` ahora nos permite acceder a los métodos y propiedades declaras en el cuerpo de la clase

> El objeto `instancia` se inicializa con un valor, que en este caso es la instancia de la clase; es decir ese es el valor con el que inicia

```
let instancia = new Conexion(param1, param2)
```

Una vez claro lo anterior, entonces podemos verificar lo siguiente:

**Variable `instancia` es una instancia de la clase `Conexion`?**

Lo hacemos de este modo:

```
console.log(instancia instanceof Conexion)
```

Lo que nos devuelve

```
true
```

Del mismo modo podemos verificar al momento de inicializar a `instancia` como una *instancia* de la clase, lo que *trae por dentro* de este modo:

```
console.log(instancia)
```

Que nos devuelve lo siguiente:

```
[object Object] {
  param1: "param1",
  param2: "param2"
}
```

Podemos leer que es un *objeto* que contiene a las *propiedades* y sus valores asignados

Comment: No deberías poner `new Conexion(param1, param2)` para mantener el ejemplo?

Comment: Lo deje como puntos suspensivos, pero tienes razón lo completaré es que desde el móvil es dificil